# Vacuum Birefringence with alternating EM waves

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, birefringence

I read [1] that in the presence of strong **static** electric or magnetic fields in vacuum the refractive index changes in such a way that there is a difference of refractive index between parallel and orthogonal waves.
My question is whether a similar effect can be observed if an **alternating** electromagnetic field is applied? I am guessing that it is indeed the case, but shouldn't this effect be more predominant in the alternating case, because my guess is that a time derivative would be involved in the derivation and thus the refractive index would be dependent upon product of electromagnetic field strength and frequency?

[1] Magnetoelectric birefringences of the quantum vacuum G.L.J.A. Rikken and C. Rizzo, 2000, Phys. Rev. A, Vol.63, 012107 (2000)

Comment: By **alternating* electromagnetic field, what AC frequency range are you thinking of? Audio? RF? Microwave? etc.

Comment: I don't know myself. But my guess is it should be high.